# Why is there extra white space in this svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I how do I remove the extra whitespace in this svg? When I inspect the blue curve is is the path and the highlighted blue is the entire svg. I don't understand I tried adjusting the view box and a couple different properties it didn't work?

The .grey-curve-svg is just an empty div with no styles.

Here is the svg:

```html
<div class="grey-curve-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#0099ff" 
          fill-opacity="1" 
          style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#007acc;"  
          data-darkreader-inline-fill="" 
          d="M0,320L120,298.7C240,277,480,235,720,234.7C960,235,1201,277,1320,298.7L1440,320L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z" 
          ></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[image: svg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [viewBox](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) area has a lot of blank space in it at the top. Adjusting the viewBox dimensions can fix that...

```html
<div class="grey-curve-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 230 1440 320">
    <path fill="#0099ff" 
          fill-opacity="1" 
          style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#007acc;"  
          data-darkreader-inline-fill="" 
          d="M0,320L120,298.7C240,277,480,235,720,234.7C960,235,1201,277,1320,298.7L1440,320L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z" 
          ></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) determines the visible dimensions in the SVG.

Yours is `0 0 1440 320` (*min-x*, *min-y*, *width* and *height*). You can alter it to crop the contents of the svg. Something like `viewBox="0 230 1440 100"` looks like it fits better

```html
<div class="grey-curve-svg">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 230 1440 100">
    <path fill="#0099ff" 
          fill-opacity="1" 
          style="--darkreader-inline-fill:#007acc;"  
          data-darkreader-inline-fill="" 
          d="M0,320L120,298.7C240,277,480,235,720,234.7C960,235,1201,277,1320,298.7L1440,320L1440,320L1320,320C1200,320,960,320,720,320C480,320,240,320,120,320L0,320Z" 
          ></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers said to alter the viewBox, yet simply `viewbox="0 0 1 1"` worked for me as my child graphics superseded those dimensions.